# Can I log in to my site from my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to make a log in or sign up feature for my web site in my iPhone app. My website is a content management system, and like any other CMS, it has log in and registration features. It also has permmissions, dependent on the user account. I think I would have to use `UIWebView` for this.

Are there any examples or tutorials I can examine?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for [`NSURLRequest`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (and [`NSMutableURLRequest`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html)): you can use it to make a `POST` request to your login and registration pages, just like a web browser. You can write the form UI in Cocoa/Objective-C and then send the data to the server.

As far as displaying the result to the user, you'll have to figure out a way to either parse the returned HTML (bad idea) or modify your CMS to return JSON or XML to iPhone requests (better idea).

**Edit:** Here's some sample code, taken from an app I'm working on (it submits data to Last.fm using `POST`):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/"];
NSString *str = @"This is my example data!";

// everything below here is directly from my app:
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setValue:kLastFMClientUserAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];

*connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request
                                              delegate:self
                                      startImmediately:YES];
```

Comment: sorry i saw the example code on the developer website but non of them seem to help with what i am tyring to do you said a good idea but, would there be a source code sample i could see?